# java stream null check

Tags: java, stream

**How to better way to check null values inside stream**

```
List<Employee> employees1= employees.stream().filter(
                    employee -> students.stream()
                        .anyMatch(student ->
                               // checking null
                                employee!=null && student!=null &&
                                employee.getId()!=null && student.getName()!=null &&
                                employee.getId()==student.getId() &&
                                employee.getName().equals(student.getName()))
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious to see if your code throws a `NullPointerException` during execution. You are streaming your `employees` collection and then a `students` collection within the `Employee` object.

If your parent object, `Employee`, is a null value then you cannot possibly have a `student` collection on that object, as indicated in your inner-stream.

Consider introducing:

```
.map(employee -> Optional.ofNullable(employee) 
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
```

before your filter. This will eliminate any null parent objects.

For your inner-stream, you still seem concerned that your `student` element is going to be null, so repeat these lines before your `.anyMatch` call.

For readability, I would consider extracting your null checks into smaller methods that describe what checks are being performed. For example you have the line:

```
employee.getName().equals(student.getName()
```

which suggests that you're looking for student elements where the employee and student names match. `employeeAndStudentNamesMatch(employee, student)` would suffice here.

For checking null values, you should really use the `Optional` API. This gives you options to wrap something that is potentially null in a safe wrapper to check if there is a value there or not. Extracting an example from your inner stream where you're checking for the presence of a student's name you can replace this with:

```
Optional.ofNullable(student.getName()).isPresent();
```

This is all the advice that I can really offer. Hope it helps you progress.

Comment: Probably, I have two object Student, Employe & finding only those object which have same name and id, rather employe and student coming from database, that may be chance to wether any field cab be null.

Comment: I would suggest changing your database schema to prohibit null values, especially on your primary keys - id. Implementing this at the database layer will definitely help you in the long run so you don't have to manually examine your results in Java. Good luck! :-)